Can't repair chrome remote desktop host on ubuntu 24.04
My connection to Ubuntu 24.04 VM recently got broke so I decided to reinstall the host app and reregister it, but I keep failing. I suspect that host ID might not get purged when installing new crd host package The steps I’m taking are:


  On Ubuntu – I removed “This device” from connection list



https://i.imgur.com/TVLiQQ2.png


  Sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop (and purged it also)



  Restarted the Ubuntu VM



  Downloaded crd package as instruction for g.co/headless suggested



https://i.imgur.com/1rqrIWv.png


  Installed the package (looks good)



https://i.imgur.com/eXT265s.png


  On my Windows laptop I generate the auth script and send it to Ubuntu VM



https://i.imgur.com/4F1T7V0.png


  On Ubuntu VM I get the script and execute it with results:



https://i.imgur.com/yy8Ojhs.png


  On my Windows laptop I see option to connect to Ubuntu VM, but PIN is wrong



https://i.imgur.com/HA7jM5x.png
The only thing I see is that host ID that exists and I’m not 100% is it removed. Maybe connection attempt tries to come to old remote desktop that doesn’t exist anymore?
I also tried to install older version as suggested here: Chrome Remote Desktop in 24.04 Anyone got such issue and solved it?
